# Cambiar el color de fondo de un texview desde una lista en el spinner en android studio con Kotlin

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-spinner

hola quería una ves mas de su ayuda  estoy comenzando en la programcion android kotlin .
como puede cambiar el color de fondo de un textview desde una lista de colores que tengo en un spinner

tengo creado drawable con los colores pero no se como hago para que al selecionar un color de lista cambie el color de fondo de ese textview

```
val arrayscolor= arrayOf("#FF03DAC5","#FF414141")
    spinner.adapter=ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arryscolor)

    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long
        ) {
            txtmensaje.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(position.toString()))
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
          txtmensaje.setText("")
        }

    }
```

quiero mencionar que no se como poner ese drawable a mi arrays color por ese le puse eso colores por default, quiero añadir que como hacer para que el usuario mire el color y no el numero exagecimal

ayuda gracias de ante mano

Comment: Agrega lo que has realizado por favor.

Answer (score 0):

a ver.... esta pregunta tiene infinidad de respuestas....yo lo que haria es guardar en un array los colores que quiero cargar..... por ejemplo con valores hexadecimales

```
val arrayColores=arrayOf("#123456","#987652")
```

y luego en la lista del spinner colocar

```
Naranja
rojo
verde
.....
```

y con el metodo **getSelectedItemId** aplicado al spinner que tengas creado

creo que seria algo asi

```
spinner1.getSelectedItemId()
```

te devuelve el id del item seleccionado del spinner que  los items empiezan a contarse desde el 0.

entonces asocias cada item del spinner con el array , mediante los indices, y luego cuando el usuario seleccione el item con indice igual a 1, extraes el texto del array de la posicion con indice igual a 1 y luego se lo aplicas de esta forma

```
textview1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(valor rescatado del array))
```

Comment: quiero comentear te que para cargar el color al textview lo puse de este manera

Comment: txtmensaje.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(position.toString())) pero me cierra la aplicacion

Comment: Jose, resultado complicado darte una respuesta concreto sin conocer el código, pero te comento que este código que es el que te comento al fina funciona.....   var txt=findViewById(R.id.mytextView) as TextView--------------------------------------------------                                
        txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#111111"))----------------------------revisa si coges el número de indice correcto, revisa que al parsecolor() le pasas un valor correcto......yo solo te di una idea, deberias dar más detalle de tu problema para saber donde te falla

Comment: ya lo resolvi me ayudo tu idea gracias